# How to implement multiton pattern using Spring Framework

Tags: spring, multiton

How does one implement multiton pattern using Spring Framework's facilities?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern

I want to write a factory which takes a pair of client and supplier as arguments. The factory should always return a bean of type T. For a given pair of client and supplier, the instance of T return should be a singleton, but for a different pair of client and supplier, it will be a different instance of T. Please suggest a way to implement this without implementing boilerplate code that Spring may already provide.

```
Interface ClientSdk {
    sendRequestToClient();
}

class ClientASdk implements ClientSdk {
}

class ClientBSdk implements ClientSdk {
}

enum Client {
    ClientA,
    ClientB;
}

enum Supplier {
    SupplierA,
    SupplierB;
}    

class ClientSupplier {
    private Client client;
    private Supplier supplier;
}

class SdkFactory {
    public ClientSdk getClientSdk(ClientSupplier clientSupplier) {
        //For a given ClientSupplier, always return the same 
        //ClientSupplier instance 
    }
}

@Service
class ClientRequestService {
    public sendRequestToClient(ClientSupplier clientSupplier) {
          ClientSdk clientSdk = SdkFactory.getSdk(clientSupplier);
          clientSdk.sendRequestToClient();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is T? How does it relate to the client/supplier pairs? Per that link you supply, you can implement this with a single global map. A key in the map would exist for each client/supplier pair. When an entry is looked for in the map and doesn't yet exist, it would be created via a Spring Prototype bean. This is much like how I've created per-thread beans in the past using a thread-local variable. In that case, the keys in the map are basically thread ids. - I don't of any other help Spring can be but to offer the notion of a Prototype bean.  This pattern is easy to implement.

Comment: T is interface implemented by the object being constructed. For every client/supplier pair, a T object gets specific values for its attributes. For a given client/supplier pair, once a T object is constructed, the same object must be returned for that pair. I have tried AbstractFactoryBean in Spring and its subtypes - any idea about those?

Comment: It sounds like you want to be able to define a Spring bean that generates a whole class of bean instances based on a generic Java type.  I can't think how Spring could be made to do that.  I think it would help if you supplied some code that shows the type structure of the objects you want to construct, and also show the code that will receive these objects (calls to a bean factory, autowiring, etc).  I expect that there's a solution to your problem that would let you utilize Spring beans, but I can't see it given only the information you've supplied.

Comment: @CryptoFool, description edited to include outline of code.

Comment: There is no particular support for your use case. Just make `SdkFactory` a bean and use a map inside.

Comment: You simplified your requirements, lol!  I demonstrated a more challenging set of requirements.  Please understand that you can just change the definition of  the `createSdk` method to instantiate the appropriate static subclass of `ClientSdk`.  As it is, you don't have to mark those classes as Spring Beans explicitly, as the annotations on the `createSdk` method will make sure that any instance it returns is instrumented as a Spring Bean.  This is the only way to go when creating specific instances on the fly.  Given a static set of ClientSdk subtypes, there are other ways you could go.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution to your problem.  It does make `SdkFactory` a bean as @crizzis suggests, but it also creates bean instances for each `ClientSdk` instance so that each of them can be autowired or otherwise helped out by Spring.  Note that I added an `ident()` method to the `ClientSdk` interface just to show that the `MyClientSdk` beans have in fact been autowired with the Spring `Environment`:

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryAware;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

interface ClientSdk {
    void sendRequestToClient();
}

// This class is instantiated via a @Bean method inside SdkFactory. Since it is annotated as a Prototype bean,
// multiple instances of this class can be created as beans.
class MyClientSdk implements ClientSdk {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    private final String clientSupplier;

    MyClientSdk(String clientSupplier) {
        this.clientSupplier = clientSupplier;
        System.out.printf("@@@ Created MyClientSdk for: %s\n", clientSupplier);
    }

    public void sendRequestToClient() {
        System.out.printf("Sending request for client: %s\n", clientSupplier);
        System.out.printf("CS: %s  Environment Prop: %s\n", clientSupplier, environment.getProperty("spring.application.name"));
    }
}

@Component
class SdkFactory implements BeanFactoryAware {

    private Map<String, ClientSdk> sdks = new HashMap<>();
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    // Here's the key logic to insure that we get just one instance of ClientSdk per clientSupplier value.
    ClientSdk getClientSdk(String clientSupplier) {
        if (!sdks.containsKey(clientSupplier))
            sdks.put(clientSupplier, beanFactory.getBean(ClientSdk.class, clientSupplier));
        return sdks.get(clientSupplier);
    }

    // This is probably the most important bit.  This creates a Spring Bean unique to a particular 'clientSupplier'
    // value, but only does so when requested so that the factory can control when these beans are created, creating
    // only one per a particular `clientSupplier` value.
    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    ClientSdk createSdk(String clientSupplier) {
        return new MyClientSdk(clientSupplier);
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }
}

@Service
class ClientRequestService {

    @Autowired
    SdkFactory factory;

    public void sendRequestToClient(String clientSupplier) {
        ClientSdk clientSdk = factory.getClientSdk(clientSupplier);
        clientSdk.sendRequestToClient();
    }
}


@SpringBootApplication
public class HarmonyTestApp implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    ClientRequestService service;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ApplicationContext applicationContext = new SpringApplication(new Class<?>[]{HarmonyTestApp.class}).run(args);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        service.sendRequestToClient("client1");
        service.sendRequestToClient("client2");
        service.sendRequestToClient("client1");
        service.sendRequestToClient("client1");
        service.sendRequestToClient("client2");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
@@@ Created MyClientSdk for: client1
Sending request for client: client1
CS: client1  Environment Prop: TestApp
@@@ Created MyClientSdk for: client2
Sending request for client: client2
CS: client2  Environment Prop: TestApp
Sending request for client: client1
CS: client1  Environment Prop: TestApp
Sending request for client: client1
CS: client1  Environment Prop: TestApp
Sending request for client: client2
CS: client2  Environment Prop: TestApp
```

Note that per the output, each of `client1`'s and `client2`'s ClientSdk objects are only created once, even though they're used multiple times.  Also notice that since the call to `ident()` in `sendRequestToClient` prints the value of a property obtained by an autowired `Environment` instance, autowiring of each `ClientSdk` object has worked.

I do realize that I used a `String` instead of a `ClientSupplier` object as the identifying key for each ClientSdk object.  I did that just to keep the example as simple as I could.  I expect you can expand the example to replace the `clientSupplier` `String` with an instance of `ClientSupplier` and somehow use that object as the key/identifier to insure that just one `ClientSdk` instance is created per `ClientSupplier`.  That detail isn't really germain to the basic idea here.

Also, please note that the question itself changed while I was working on my implementation.  Given that there are now exactly two subclasses of ClientSdk, you could simply make those regular `@Component` Spring beans.  Having a small static number of those makes this problem less interesting.  The technique I demonstrate here allows for an unlimited number of bean instances of `ClientSdk` class without having to define a unique class for each of them.  This requires that Spring create arbitrary instances of them based on runtime information.  This was what the original form of the question seemed to be asking for.

Comment: Now you all can see that I'm bored and have no life, LOL. :). I wanted to see how fast I could throw this idea together.  It went together quickly.  Adding the comments and surrounding explanation took longer than writing the code, as is often the case with a S.O. answer of any complexity.

Comment: thanks, appreciate all your effort. I tried out the code above and somehow have to remove Component from SdkFactory and make createSdk private, without which the IntelliJ tells me it needs arguments of createSdk and the factory's constructor to be beans. With those changes, it says it cannot find a bean of type Sdk on calling beanFactory.getBean(). Regardless, your code won me more than half the battle. For now I have left our BeanFactoryAware and am calling private createSdk instead of beanFactory.getBean() and removed Bean and Scope.

Comment: @jerry.pepper - Ooops.  I should have mentioned that IntelliJ warning to you.  I get that periodically, and I ignore it. It's a bug I think.  IntelliJ doesn't see that it's a Prototype Bean and therefore doesn't have to be instantiated by Spring initially.  This means that it can be instantiated explicitly, at which point you can provide a constructor parameter, as we're doing.  I've read about it, and it's a perfectly fine thing to do.  IntelliJ just can't figure it out.  I've had a few of these in production for years with no trouble.  I keep hoping IntelliJ will fix it.